# Solving AM-GM without expanding

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that $(p^2+p+1)(q^2+q+1)(r^2+r+1)(s^2+s+1) ≥ 81pqrs$ for all $p, q, r, s ≥ 0$. I am not sure how to solve this problem. I know that this is supposed to be an AM-GM question, so I tried expanding it. It didn't take long for me to realize that expanding is probably not the way to go to solve this problem. I also tried taking the fourth root of both sides, but that didn't solve anything either. How can I prove this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To quote https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h554400p3221583: $p^2 + 1 \ge 2p$.

Comment: use $$x^2+x+1\ge 3x\iff {(x-1)}^2\ge 0$$

Comment: See my answer below, you need all numbers to be nonnegative/positive, or the inequality won't hold. Look at this desmos link, it shows a counterexample to this inequality if you allow s,r  to be negative https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s6mo53maly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the original problem in my math book, "The Art of Problem Solving: Intermediate Algebra", and it says that all $p,q,r,s$ are positive, which is important to note to solve this problem.

Apply AM-GM to the terms $p^2,p,1$. We get $\frac{p^2+p+1}3 \ge \sqrt[3]{p^2*p*1}$. Simplifying and rearranging we get $p^2+p+1 \ge 3p$. Now apply the same logic to each of the other expressions to get $q^2+q+1 \ge 3q$, $r^2+r+1 \ge 3r$, and $s^2+s+1 \ge 3s$. Since all of $p,q,r,s$ are positive, then all of these expressions are positive, too, so we can safely multiply all the inequalities together to get $(p^2+p+1)(q^2+q+1)(r^2+r+1)(s^2+s+1) \ge 81pqrs$ as desired.